# What is the meaning of "being of order $Y$"?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that $f(x)$ is said to be approximately equals to $g(x)$; i.e., $f(x) \sim g(x)$, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$. But thinking about it as a synonym of "a quantity $X$  is of order $Y$" does not solve my problem; which probably means that I'm misinterpreting the concepts.

I'll quote the exactly piece of text from where this question emerged, which is the context of Percolation Theory; but feel free to use whatever example you want.

> [$\cdots$] the number of annuli in the dual lattice of the form $A(3^{k+1}, 3k) + \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$, with $k$ even and $\geq 2$, that are in the interior of $\partial B(n)$, is of order $\log n$. More precisely, there is a $c > 0$ such that for each $n$ the number of such annuli is at least $c \log n$.

One more time, there is no need to focus on the Percolation aspect of the problem; instead it would be interesting to have a notion of what the expressions "of order" and "there is a $c > 0$ such that [$\cdots$]" mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on Big O notation describes "on the order of" as the same as your approximately equal.  I am more familiar with it being like Big Theta, that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}\to c$ for $c$ some constant.  I might say that the area of a circle is of order $r^2$, ignoring the factor $\pi$, so it would fail the Wikipedia definition.

In your quote, the number of annuli is growing with $n$.  The statement that it is of order $\log n$ gives you an idea how fast it grows.  It isn't linear in $n$, or even $\sqrt n$, but it is faster than $\log \log n$.  The more precisely part is in one sense less precise, as it does not rule out faster growth.  It does say you can find one multiplicative constant $c$ that works for all $n$.  This rules out growth rates like $\frac {\log n}{\log \log n}$ because given any fixed $c$ you could make $n$ large enough to fall below $c \log n$